Typescript code generator using compiler API
I want to generate some code using annotations in typescript
@PSate
class State {
  name = "First";
 
 changeName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// generate new files based on class State fields and methods AST

In dart we have https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner
How can I achieve something similar in Typescript?
